# odata controller. Correct why to implement get by key

Tags: odata

I have adapted this pattern from a [pluralsight](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/asp-dot-net-odata-v4-restful-api/table-of-contents) course. Because of the ability to return the correct http codes.

```
public virtual IHttpActionResult Get(int key)
{
    IQueryable<T> result = Repository.AsQueryable().Where(p => p.Id == key);

    if (!result.Any())
        return NotFound();

    return Ok(SingleResult.Create(result));
}
```

The problem is in the return format.

```
{
   "@odata.context":"https://localhost:44300/odata/$metadata#Reports/$entity","Id":1,"Name":"Test Report#1","Description":"Min f\u00f8rste rapport","CategoryTypeId":1,"OrganizationId":1,"Definition":null,"AccessModifier":"Local","ObjectOwnerId":1,"LastChanged":"2016-08-18T12:57:48.3735722+02:00","LastChangedByUserId":1
}
```

It's a mix of context meta data and entity properties in the same json object. there is nothing wrong with that according to [microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/leohu/2013/10/04/odata-and-json-payload-examples/) it's just hard to work with.

Is there a way to correct this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an Accept header with `application/json; odata.metadata=none` the metadata will be stripped.